# rails wicked gem has_one association and nested form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms, has-one, wicked-gem

On my form on has_one association the fields do not appear for a singular form.

`<%= f.fields_for :pack_social_media_sur_mesure, @commande.pack_social_media_sur_mesure do |ff| %>`

remains empty

i think i missed something...

My Models :

Commande model :

```
class Commande < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  validates_presence_of :user
  has_one :pack_social_media_sur_mesure, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :pack_social_media_sur_mesure, allow_destroy: true
end
```

PackSocialMediaSurMesure  model :

```
class PackSocialMediaSurMesure < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :commande
  ...
end
```

My controller :

```
class CommandeStepsController < ApplicationController
  ...    
  def update
    @user_id = current_user.id
    @user = current_user
    @commande = @user.commande
    @commande.update(commande_params)
  end
  ...
  def commande_params
    params.require(:commande).permit(:id,..., pack_social_media_sur_mesure_attributes: [:id, ...])
  end
end
```

My form :

```
<%= form_for @commande, url: wizard_path, html: { class: "pack-slide" }, method: :put do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :pack_social_media_sur_mesure, @commande.pack_social_media_sur_mesure do |ff| %>
    <%= ff.select :question1 %>
    ...
  <% end %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

PS : I use wicked gem for this form, this why `wizard_path`.

Thx,
Théo

Answer (score 0):

Ok I find.

The reason why the fields do not appear is that I had already created an 'commande' but not a 'pack_social_media_sur_mesure'. Or the "wicked gem" takes us to the edit path but we cannot edit it if it does not exist.

The solution was to create the pack_social_media_sur_mesure when creating the 'order' as bellow :

```
class CommandesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_commande, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  ...

  def create
    @commande = current_user.create_commande(commande_params)
    if @commande.save
      if @commande.pack_social_media_sur_mesure == nil
        @commande.create_pack_social_media_sur_mesure(...)
      end
      redirect_to ...
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  ...

  def set_commande
    @commande = current_user.commande
  end
```